# Labeling points of intersection between plots

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

First of all I would like to apologize for the newbie question.
I am just starting up with mathematica and I have 2 simple plots. What i want to do is have Mathematica automatically find the intersections, label them and show me the coordinates.
I have searched this forum and there are a lot of similar questions, but they are too advanced for me.
Can someone explain how i can do this the easiest way?
[image: this is what I have]

Comment: See this: [Labeling points of intersection between plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32081/363)

Comment: I did Chris. I was just hoping someone would explain it because its too complicated for me. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve for equality. Get values for the points using [replacement](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) : `points = {x, x^2} /. sol` would work just as well.  Offset the labels and set as text in epilog.

```
sol = Solve[x^2 == x + 2, x];
points = {x, x + 2} /. sol;
offset = Map[# + {0, 3} &, points];
Plot[{x^2, x + 2}, {x, -6, 6},
 Epilog -> {Thread[Text[points, offset]],
   Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[points]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris! can you please explain what is happening after the EPILOG -> ...? after that i got lost. What is Thread?

Comment: We have `points = {{-1, 1}, {2, 4}}` and `offset = {{-1, 4}, {2, 7}}`
and for the labels we need `{Text[{-1, 1}, {-1, 4}], Text[{2, 4}, {2, 7}]}`, where the second pair of coordinates are for the label position.  This can be done using `Thread[Text[points, offset]]` or `MapThread[Text, {points, offset}]`.  See the documentation: [Thread](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html), [MapThread](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html), [Epilog](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html), [Text](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html).